# I can not change the height of a cell in UITableView, but the size is set?

Tags: ios, swift

I can not change the height of a cell in UITableView, but the size is set?

[Screen of cell settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQPji.png)

[Simulator screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiHRJ.png)

UPDATE:

I found the difference between my code(github.com/gemcave/dn-ios-design-study) and the code of the tutorial(designcode.io/cloud/Chapter3Part2-Swift2/11-TableViewClass.zip ), but it still does not work

```
`override func viewDidLoad() { 
super.viewDidLoad() 
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100 
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from your cells height, also check the table view property for height of cell, make it also 100, like in the below image

[image]

No need to use the code for that.

Comment: Why lesson for which I do not set the table row height -https://designcode.io/cloud/Chapter3Part2-Swift2/11-TableViewClass.zip

Comment: I found the difference between his code and the code of the tutorial, but it still does not work 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by implementing the **tableview** delegate method.

First check the **IBOutlet connection**  of you **tableView** and set "*table view*" **data source** and **delegate**

And then implement this method

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100.0;
}
```

Comment: otherwise you will get default size 44

Comment: it's already custom and height set  to 100(in "Screen of cell setting" i show it), but without your code it doesn't work

Comment: all you cell has different height? if yes, you must do implement this method

Comment: other wise you can use Custom prototype Cell inside table view from storyboard / xib file

Answer (score 0):

Add a height constraint in storyboard and set it to 100 for the cell.

Comment: "Pin" settings disable, i can't

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return (yourHeight);
}
```